# not receiving name of the group in activity object of groupChat conversation update. MSBot framework for Teams (nodejs)

Tags: botframework, microsoft-teams

When someone add my bot to their group chat in the activity object of **conversationUpdate** event I am not receiving the name of the group chat.

```
{
    "membersAdded": [
        {
            "id": "28:306a0c33-333-47ce-a9f8-03799e676dc2"
        }
    ],
    "type": "conversationUpdate",
    "timestamp": "2020-05-14T19:55:28.0039315Z",
    "id": "f:9476c223-fd49-7a31-06b9-d97ff3fd4d76",
    "channelId": "msteams",
    "serviceUrl": "https://smba.trafficmanager.net/in/",
    "from": {
        "id": "29:1q1sbfe3sRPvYJgi-PwHztKmrnLj7ozY233ciqF2CRitV0cOgY5ldNxWtJMDVMmXYuItSHM5xETWmlyuZvoEGXg",
        "aadObjectId": "d1ac8255-7079-4bff-bda6-1593f42e7d52"
    },
    "conversation": {
        "isGroup": true,
        "conversationType": "groupChat",
        "tenantId": "86b9a961-9303-4cc1-b78d-62d07f6ab178",
        "id": "19:29da1fbb91314556a8bba82eaf17ea61@thread.v2"
    },
    "recipient": {
        "id": "28:306a0c33-333-47ce-a9f8-03799e676dc2",
        "name": "testbot"
    },
    "channelData": {
        "tenant": {
            "id": "86b9a961-9303-4cc1-b78d-62d07f6ab178"
        }
    }
}
```

is there any way I can get the name of the groupChat ?

Answer (score 0):

@Nikhil, You do not get the Team name in member added event.Team name will be passed only in case of team rename event. Please check the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/bots/how-to/conversations/conversation-basics?tabs=dotnet#teams-channel-data) for more details.